# Usage and Implementation of Head, Option, Trace http methods with Servlet

Tags: java, forms, http, servlets, web

I want to implement following methods to understand their working by using Servlet.

```
doHead()  
doTrace()  
doHead()  
doOption()
doDelete()
```

The syntax and theoretical meaning is given in every tutorial and documentation but I didn't find their actual use and implementation.

Can u plz help me out with scenarios in which we use these methods and actual implementation code.

I tried to call these function from html form and implemented respective method but it is not working.

```
<form action="trace" method="trace">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<form action="trace" method="option">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Refer to the HTTP specification to understand the semantics of HTTP requests in general and each HTTP method specifically. These servlet methods are just a reflection of the HTTP standard.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tpolnik said, you'd better understand the semantics of those HTTP methods firstly. Here is a table of brief description to those methods, which is extracted from [RFC 7231 - Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1).

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Method  | Description                                     | Sec.  |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+
| GET     | Transfer a current representation of the target | 4.3.1 |
|         | resource.                                       |       |
| HEAD    | Same as GET, but only transfer the status line  | 4.3.2 |
|         | and header section.                             |       |
| POST    | Perform resource-specific processing on the     | 4.3.3 |
|         | request payload.                                |       |
| PUT     | Replace all current representations of the      | 4.3.4 |
|         | target resource with the request payload.       |       |
| DELETE  | Remove all current representations of the       | 4.3.5 |
|         | target resource.                                |       |
| CONNECT | Establish a tunnel to the server identified by  | 4.3.6 |
|         | the target resource.                            |       |
| OPTIONS | Describe the communication options for the      | 4.3.7 |
|         | target resource.                                |       |
| TRACE   | Perform a message loop-back test along the path | 4.3.8 |
|         | to the target resource.                         |       |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Since most of the modern browsers don't support submit a form using methods other than `GET` and `POST`, it doesn't make sense to use `TRACE` or `OPTION` as a method to transfer user's data to an HTTP server. See [this W3C document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) for more information.

Comment: I didn't found any useful information for these functions on Wc3 document as well.

Comment: @ShamsuddinAltamash Most browsers may only support `GET` and `POST` when submitting a form as the document recommends. I think you'd better try to choose another way to make an `HEAD` or `OPTION` request such as AJAX or other http clients like Chrome extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).